# Installing Python Chromagnon for OSX Terminal to extract/restore Google Chrome tabs

Tags: macos, google-chrome, terminal, python, github

I saw this suggestion posted here https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19500/tool-to-read-data-from-google-chrome-snss-files/19501 but am not sure how to install it for OSX. I'm looking to pull links from the Last Tabs/Session files in Chrome's Default folder b/c Chrome failed to reload all the previous tabs when relaunching. It somehow loaded less than 1/5 of the tabs i had open previously, but with no errors or option to restore tabs (and renaming the last tabs/session files to current tabs/session didn't work - it just opened the same ones as before, and i did copy the files before closing the browser).

I assume the lines under 'Test' at the bottom of this wiki https://github.com/JRBANCEL/Chromagnon/wiki/Reverse-Engineering-SNSS-Format need to be entered in Terminal, but i don't know where to install the Chromagnon files (I also posted an instruction request on Github).

Also, if anyone has suggestions other than this please let me know. I saw this recommended in some older posts but it looks like it's no longer available or functional: https://github.com/lsauer/chrome-session-restore

I installed Session Buddy so this should do the trick if it happens again. If i can extract the tab links from my saved Tabs/Session files with Chromagnon that should be all i need for now.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

OK. This was years ago, and you have probably given up by now, but for the next person who wants to do this..

1. Parsing these SNSS files is hard. Much easier to just use strings, like this:

   > % strings Last\ Tabs
   >       SNSS
   >       chrome://history/
   >       chrome://history/
   >       %

In my case, (files from a crashed PC), the "Last Tabs" file was basically empty (2 URLs in there)

2. Another way to find out what you were looking at is the History file. That is usually huge, but you can get the last 10 URIs like this:

> % strings History | grep http | tail | head -n 3
>       https://www.k5learning.com/worksheets/math/grade-5-metric-units-length-decimals-d.pdfIZ
>       https://www.k5learning.com/worksheets/math/grade-5-metric-units-length-decimals-c.pdfHZ
>       https://www.k5learning.com/worksheets/math/grade-5-metric-units-length-decimals-b.pdfGZ

(sorry about the formatting - blockquote doesn't seem to work?)